# Word translation

Tags: translation, characters, traditional-characters, character-identification

[image: characters]

Can someone please help me identify these chinese or japanese characters and what they translate in english?

If you could please answer in such a way to clearly distinguish between the large word and small word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small characters are 有田 (owns rice field)

The big character is 雅 (elegant)

有田 (Arita) is a common Japanese surname

有田雅 may be a Japanese name  'Miyabi Arita' in kanji

Comment: So 雅 means Miyabi?

Comment: 'Miyabi ' is the English pronunciation of  the Japanese kanji '雅' (ミヤビ) . 雅 in Chinese is pronounced as Yǎ